# How to open google maps direction with multiple waypoint using Linking in React Native in single linking

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

For example i have 3 locations, I need to google maps directions with linking URL,

```
locations = [
    {
        lat : 1.310494,
        long : 103.815954
    },
    {
        lat : 1.301569,
        long : 103.785721
    },
    {
        lat : 1.278916,
        long : 103.825573
    },
]
```

how can i use this params **locations** tobe waypoint to open the google maps app

Answer (score 1):

i slove with this url

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/{**waypoints_lot_and_lang**}
```

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/1.310494,103.815954/1.301569,103.785721/1.278916,103.825573/

Answer (score 0):

location.map((item)=>{
return (
<Pressable
onPress={() =>
Linking.openURL(
`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${item.lat},${item.long}`,
)
}>
);
})

Comment: not like this, 1 single return with multiple address (waypoint)